# MongoDB in laravel stopped working from one day to another

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, connection

I'm facing an issue right now which is really annoying, we are working on a project using laravel as an api, with mongodb as a database. Everything worked fine, the connections were good and I was able to see everything in the database, but one day, everything stopped working.

I have this issue :

```
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeOutException : No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [TLS handshake failed: error: 1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed calling 
hello on 'ecpodac-shard-00-01.jleen.mongodb.net:27017'] [TLS handshake failed: error: 1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed calling
hello on 'ecpodac-shard-00-02.jllen.mongodb.net:27017'] [TLS handshake failed: error: 1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verif in file C:\Users\
oliver\Desktop\C-COD-260-NCE-2-3-ecp-remi.triton\back\back\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\functions.php on line 440
```

[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAhxd.jpg)

So, we did some researches and for now we tried :

Adding my own IP adress even if we had authorized all connections in mongoAtlas,
Cut all firewalls and antivirus,
Remove entirely my project and getting it back with a functionnal version
Rewrite the connection in Laravel itself
Removing php from my computer and reinstalled it

Honestly, I don't know what to do anymore, so maybe you have a solution to offer me ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: That image is kind of hard to read, could you edit the text of the error into the question?

Comment: Ok, I edited it

Comment: `certificate verify failed` - if it stopped working from one day to the next, check the client, server, intermediate, and root certificates to see which one expired.